# PHPUnit and Zend: Testing a function on a controller?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I have a controller called "SiteController". On it there is a normal indexAction which displays the frontpage. It's fairly easy to test this, but how would I test another function that is NOT an action with parameters. Let's say I have a function called "sendMail($to, $message)". How do I test that?

```
<?php

class ControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{

    public function testShowCallsServiceFind()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/index'); // dont care about this...

        // what I need is a way to do this:
        $res = $controller->sendMail("bla", "bla"); // so that I can test sendMail? 

    }
}
```

How can I test sendMail?

Answer (score 0):

You dont actually need to call the dispatch method, you can new up a controller object and call methods directly:

```
$controller = new \My\Controller();

$actual_result = $controller->sendMail($params);

$this->assertEquals($expected_result, $actual_result);
```

Be careful though, you'll need to 'mock' your dependencies so you don't actually send a real email when you run your tests! http://phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html